# Java - clone class based on array

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a class called NewClass, and inside this class I have another class called people. I want to make clones of the people class, and have them with different values and names; however, I want these classes named based on a String array.

Lets say I have a String array with 5 words:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" };
```

And I have a class with a few variables like:

```
class people
{
    String name;
    int id;
}
```

Is it possible to clone or create a new class, using "people" as the model with the Strings from array? I've tried this so far and it doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    people array[i] = new people();
}
```

Also, how would these classes be accessed from outside the "NewClass"; would it be possible to access like this:

```
class OtherClass
{
    NewClass myclass = new NewClass();
    System.out.println(myclass.first.name);
}
```

Comment: Be more specific. I guess, you want to _instantiate_ the people class, rather than cloning it? If that is the case, you would need to provide getters/setters or an appropriate constructor to set the name variable.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question right, you might want to get a book on basic Java programming where they describe the use of class objects and constructors.  With that being said, you would want to create a constructor within People to accept a string input that goes into the name, and call people array[i] = new people(array[i]);

Answer (score 0):

You really should read a Java tutorial.

Your code is wrong at so many levels (starting with not following Java naming conventions, and improperly using the technical term `clone` for transforming an array of strings into an array of other objects), its hard to give you a concise answer.

Really, read a Java tutorial. They'll tell you how to make an `People[]` array. Or even better: an `ArrayList<People>`.

From reading a well-written tutorial or book you **will learn much more** than from the short answers you can expect to get here. See: the tutorials and books are often written by people who teach professionally...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically set variable names based on Strings. You've already shown us a better example- creating an array of 'people' class and filling it with 'people' objects (Java best practices suggests using a capital at the start of class names though). You can easily set the 'name' field of the 'people' class in the same loop you used to instantiate all the 'people' objects by iterating through the String array. Then it is as simple as knowing the index of the 'people' object you want to retrieve.

```
peopleArray = new people[array.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    peopleArray[i] = new people();
    peopleArray[i].name = array[i];
}
```

Then just:

```
System.out.println(peopleArray[index].name);
```

You can simplify it by writing a constructor for the 'people' class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But if you really want to dynamically set variable names based on Strings you need a HashMap.
Here is an example.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Person(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person - name = " + name + ", id = " + id;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    private static HashMap<String, Person> people = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] keys = { "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"};
        String[] names = { "Emily", "Bob", "Susan", "Bill", "Alice"};
        int[] ids = {1, 2, 3, 4,5};
        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            Person p = new Person(names[i], ids[i]);
            people.put(keys[i], p);
        }

        System.out.println(people.get("first"));
        System.out.println(people.get("second"));
    }
}
```

But I doubt that you actually need to do this. Maybe all you want to do is set the name of the person to a string from the array. In which case you don't need the HashMap.

Comment: This is misleading.  You're not actually "dynamically set[ting] variable names based on Strings".  You're just making the key in a `HashMap` a `String`.  There's a big difference between those two concepts.